# how to get the keys of a collection in VB6.0

Tags: vb6

I am debugging a VB 6.0 application which deals a lot in collections. In one such scenario the application is fetching the object from a collection using text entered in a textbox as a key.

Now I want to know what key needs to be entered in the textbox for me to fetch the required object in the collection.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question fully - can you elaborate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you're asking is that given a collection of objects, and an object that you know is in that collection, how do you determine the object's key in the collection.  The answer is that this value is not stored anywhere, it is only specified when you add the element to the collection.  So general practice is that when you add the element, you make the collection key some property or combination of properties on the object, so that you can calculate what the key would be given the object.